# Variable delay element

Tags: vhdl, delay

This code if compiled has an error appear with (k) symbol. I need to implement this simple block. k (that represents the amount of delay) will come to my block from the previous block.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity delay is 
port( in_delay : in std_logic ;
       k : time ;
      out_delay : out std_logic);

end delay;
architecture behave of delay is

begin 
  process (in_delay )
   begin
   out_delay <= in_delay  after k ns;
  end process ; 
end behave;
```

Comment: Have you tried a different identifier? 'k' is the x1000 suffix, so might not work.

Comment: i change k to other variable and error is appeared.

mmmmmmmmm.vhd(16): near "ns": expecting ';'

if i change the variable to a constant , it works .but i need variable delay

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the `ns`, which is a units indicator used only when specifying a literal time. You can't use it after a variable name. Change that line to:

```
out_delay <= in_delay after k;
```

BTW, this sort of statement is fine as part of, say, a simulation testbench, but any statement that includes an `after` clause cannot be synthesized into real hardware.

Answer (score 0):

As Dave says, your `k` is already of `time` type and therefore already known what units it is in (you might pass in `1 us` and get a 1000ns delay for example).  If you want to pass in an integer and have it interpreted as a number of nanoseconds, you can do this:

```
out_delay <= in_delay after some_int * 1 ns;
```